# Remove left and right padding in recyclerview list

Tags: android

I have been loading images in `recyclerview` list. In that left and right side of the image having some padding.

I need to remove those padding.But I'm not sure how the paddings were added at left and right side of the `recyclerview` items.

Below I have posted the screen shot and code relevant to this:

[image]

As in the above screenshot, you can see the small left and right padding.I need to remove that.

**Edited:**

**Activity Code:**

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_list_tab_home_recycler);

mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
//  recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
recyclerView.setAdapter(homePostitemsAdapter);
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

**activity_layout.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_home_activity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_list_tab_home_recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**adapter_layout:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_vertical_list"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/post_items_layout_middle_home"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                 android:id="@+id/ll_posted_image_parent"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:orientation="vertical"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/tv_user_posted_msg_post_items_home"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content">

             </LinearLayout>
         </RelativeLayout>
     </LinearLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

**Adapter Code:**

I'm adding imageview programatically to the linearlayout.

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();


((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(d‌​m); 

int deviceWidth = dm.widthPixels; 

int deviceHeight = deviceWidth * imageHeight / imageWidth;

holder.ivPostedImageNew = new ImageView(context);
params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(deviceWidth, deviceHeight);

holder.ivPostedImageNew.setLayoutParams(params);
holder.ivPostedImageNew.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
holder.ll_posted_image_parent.addView(holder.ivPostedImageNew);
```

I'm not sure where it takes padding left and right.`All views inside the adapter having left and right padding space`.Anyone can help me with this.Thank You.

Comment: change `deviceWidth` to `LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT`

Comment: Hey stephen, in your adaptor_layout file the relativeLayout(parent) change android:layout_width="wrap_content" to android:layout_width="match_parent"

Comment: @AJ-- it is not working.I tried that one

Comment: imageview.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY); try this in ur image view @stephen

Comment: @hrskrs I tried this one already.But now also i checked, its not working.All views inside the adapter having left and right padding space

Comment: do you have a layout for items?

Comment: @mohammadrezakhalifeh adapter_layout I have posted already.

Comment: Can you post the code where deviceWidth is calculated in  this :::   params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(deviceWidth, deviceHeight);  I think this is where you are messing around

Comment: @Stallion instead of width I tried LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT.But its not working

Comment: @Stallion    `DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
                           ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
                           int deviceWidth = dm.widthPixels;
                           int deviceHeight = deviceWidth * imageHeight / imageWidth;`

Comment: @Stephen as you have use nestedscrollview 

try removing it and then check if it is the reason for unwanted padding ?
if yes, then try adding this "android:fillViewport=true"  and app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" in your nestedscrollView.

Comment: check your image? Does it have padding or white space around it. may be you are not giving padding but the image have the padding around it.

Comment: Or else try to add this params in NestedScrollView and cross check. android:fillViewport="true"  and   android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"   . fillViewport can be set through this method also setFillViewport(true);

Comment: @AJ-- I tried that one.it is not working.I have edited the post with that.

Comment: Instead of `holder.ivPostedImageNew = new ImageView(context);` try creating new `ImageView iv = new ImageView(context);`. Also change `width` of top `RelativeLayout` to `match_parent`

Comment: @Manishika There was no white space in images.I have checked.

Comment: @hrskrs it isn't worked.I tired removing holder and changed relativelayout parent width to match_parent.

Comment: From the image it seems that the problem is not in ImageView as there is right-left padding on the view below it also. Check for padding on other wrapper views

Comment: @Stephen please check out my answer

Comment: can you share your project code

Comment: First remove nested scroll view and try whether it is working or not.if it not working,can you tell me are you using any tabs like tabhost or any other?

Comment: @Bahu Yes, I'm using tabhost.inside I'm using this activity.

Comment: @Bahu I got idea from your comment. I'm using padding inside of tab. So, I removed padding inside FrameLayout in tabhost.Now images setting in full screen at home page.Thank you for this.Can you post as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check in layout whether you are giving any padding in tabhost. I think your home activity is inside tabhost.That's why you are unable to set images in full width

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I've tested Your code. First, I don't know what is YOur variable `deviceWidth` however when You do something like this:

```
holder.ivPostedImageNew = new ImageView(context);
params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(deviceWidth, deviceHeight);
holder.ivPostedImageNew.setLayoutParams(params);
holder.ivPostedImageNew.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

It is similar to code in xml:

```
<ImageView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:padding="0dp"/>
```

Which give You this:

[image]

---

So try this in Your code:

```
holder.ivPostedImageNew = new ImageView(context);
params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
ivPostedImageNew.setLayoutParams(params);
ivPostedImageNew.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
```

As a result it would be:

[image]

But You must know, if You have height of container for image smaller than the original height of image then You will need also handle it. Good solution would be use

```
ivPostedImageNew.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
```

which will center image and crop it to fit.

Comment: I have edited the post and added the device width and height

Comment: I tried your solution.its not working.I checkd all images.I am using display metrices to get the width and height of all screen devices

Comment: @Stephen could You share Your project on github?

Answer (score 0):

The image you are loading into image view has fixed size. What we need to do is that we have to strech this image so that your image will fit into image view container without any padding. It is same as we set background wallpaper in windows i.e. we use Strech, Fit to Screen, Tile, Center, etc. to set image according to our requirement.

Try to use this line after your code which you have provided

```
holder.ivPostedImageNew.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

I hope this will work...

Comment: tried this one.not working.every view inside the adapter taking extra space including imageview